# Typescript method to get and store MailChimp interests via the API

Tags: typescript, mailchimp-api-v3

I'm trying to get my Mailchimp interests by querying the API via an Audience ID; I have created the code below which retrieves everything correctly, however when I display the retrieved data outside the `forEach` loop, I'm not getting anything stored.

```
let obj = {};
let arrays = [];
let newdata;
let textlist;

try {
  const data = await mailchimp.lists.getListInterestCategories(MailChimpAudienceId);
  //console.log(data);
  const categories = data.categories;
  if (!categories.length) {
    console.log(`No categories found in Mail chimp list ${MailChimpAudienceId}`);
  }
  categories.forEach(async element => {
    //console.log(element.id);
    obj[element.title] = element.id;
    arrays.push(element.id);
    newdata = await mailchimp.lists.listInterestCategoryInterests(
      MailChimpAudienceId,
      element.id,
    );
    const interests = newdata.interests;
    interests.forEach(async element => {
      //console.log(element.id, element.name);
      obj[element.name] = element.id;
      arrays.push(element.id);
      textlist += "," + element.id;
    });
    // console.log(interests);
    console.log("obj0>>", obj);
    console.log("arr0>>", arrays);
    console.log("txt0>>", textlist);
  });
  console.log("obj1>>", obj);
  console.log("arr1>>", arrays);
  console.log("txt1>>", textlist);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("err>> ", e);
}
console.log("obj2>>", obj);
console.log("arr2>>", arrays);
console.log("txt2>>", textlist);
```

Output:

```
obj1>> { MickeyMouse: '21c3bbb614', Music: 'ac86c9d94b' }
arr1>> [ '21c3bbb614', 'ac86c9d94b' ]
txt1>> undefined
obj2>> { MickeyMouse: '21c3bbb614', Music: 'ac86c9d94b' }
arr2>> [ '21c3bbb614', 'ac86c9d94b' ]
txt2>> undefined
obj0>> {
  MickeyMouse: '21c3bbb614',
  Music: 'ac86c9d94b',
  Guitar: '9e05119885',
  Drums: 'ca5b24595d',
  Bass: '0ce6ed21da'
}
arr0>> [
  '21c3bbb614',
  'ac86c9d94b',
  '9e05119885',
  'ca5b24595d',
  '0ce6ed21da'
]
txt0>> undefined,9e05119885,ca5b24595d,0ce6ed21da
obj0>> {
  MickeyMouse: '21c3bbb614',
  Music: 'ac86c9d94b',
  Guitar: '9e05119885',
  Drums: 'ca5b24595d',
  Bass: '0ce6ed21da',
  'Big Ears': '5154e49101',
  News: 'e49c281f9f',
  Fundraising: 'aad8e5ba96'
}
arr0>> [
  '21c3bbb614',
  'ac86c9d94b',
  '9e05119885',
  'ca5b24595d',
  '0ce6ed21da',
  '5154e49101',
  'e49c281f9f',
  'aad8e5ba96'
]
txt0>> undefined,9e05119885,ca5b24595d,0ce6ed21da,5154e49101,e49c281f9f,aad8e5ba96
```

How can I store these values so that either the array, the object or the text will have the values outside the secondary loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my issue was with the async aspect of this, as shown in this answer: [Resolve await when message arrives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522558/resolve-await-when-message-arrives)

For those playing along at home, the answer was to add a timeout similar to this:

```
    setTimeout(_ => {
      // If we have categories, then display them here
      console.log(
        `Audience ID ${MailChimpAudienceId} has the interests: ${arrays}`,
      );
    }, 1000); // display after a delay
```